# Is there a list of usb 4G modems that work "as is" in Ubuntu?

Tags: usb-modem, 4g

I've been trying out different usb modems from different networks in Portugal, and each time I get a new one it's always a week-long adventure of trying to get it to work with Ubuntu, which usually ends with me quitting after following many different suggestions online.

Is there a list of supported 4G modems somewhere that I can be confident will work just by plugging them into the pc without any further hacks or tweaks?

Comment: If it's a router-modem hybrid then it presents an ethernet connection. that should work. did u find anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu has this list:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NetworkManager/Hardware/3G

However there are other modems working with ubuntu as well, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

I use a Pantech UML 295W USB dongle on Raspbian Stretch.  I get about 8Mbits/sec UP and 6 Mbits/sec down on Verizon.  Raspbian treats it as eth1, and no special drivers are required.